# Trying to reverse the order of user roles found in selector in WordPress user section

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, user-roles, wordpress-admin

Trying to change the order of the user role selector so 'Administrator' role is at top of selector with other custom roles below. Reversing the order would work. Or a DESC order .vs ASC. The selector I'm referring to is found in dashboard -> user.

I've tried working with this code: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74785/alphabetically-order-role-drop-down-selection-in-dashboard but I'm struggling in achieving a reverse order (I don't need an alphabetical list of options)

I have tried this, but I'm failing:

```
add_filter('editable_roles', function($roles){

  usort($roles, function($a, $b){
    return $a["name"] < $b["name"]?1:-1);
  });   

  return $roles;
});
```

I am able to move Administrator to the top of the list, but the other three roles/options do not change or reverse their order. Any help would be much appreciated!! I have three custom roles in addition to Administrator if that has any bearing.

Update: Here's an image of the roles. I am trying to reverse the order where Administrator is on top, and Read Only is on the bottom:
[image]

Comment: If the code you posted is the exact same you are using right now, then you got one closing bracket too much. The one after the "-1);". You should probably run your code through a linter so you can catch errors like that.

Comment: Thanks.I did run it through a linter and made changes, but it's still crashing ... I found in core where I can change the order. /wp-admin/includes/template.php, at wp_dropdown_roles() but that function isn't pluggable. I can't filter it without modifying core.. that's where I'm at.

Comment: But [wp_dropdown_roles()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_roles/) is using [get_editable_roles()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_editable_roles/) and that has the `editable_roles` filter. It's the correct function, the correct hook and the correct approach to reversing the order. Maybe there's another plugin that interferes with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and really all you want to do is to simply reverse the order of the `$roles` array, then just do this:

```php
add_filter('editable_roles', function ($roles) {
    $roles = array_reverse($roles);
    return $roles;
});
```

Function References:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/editable_roles/
- https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: Thanks DRougueRonin. I'm still struggling with this though. You understand. I am trying to reverse an array of user role names, that are options (found in the role selector). My site breaks running the above and this: `add_filters('editable_roles', 'reverse_order', 11, 2);
    function reverse_order($roles) {
        $roles2 = array_reverse($roles ,'reverse_order');
        return $roles2;
    }`

Comment: Your site shouldn't be breaking from that. I literally just copied your code (the code in your comment) and it's working in my env. There must be something else unrelated to your question that's causing the break.

Comment: It's the add_filters function you used in place of add_filter. Just a typo, fix it.

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad! I guess the environment that I used for testing had "add_filters" defined somewhere, hence why it was working for me when I copied the code to check.